# TNS listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack? in nodejs using node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle10g, node-oracledb

Even though i am releasing connections after finishing the execution of my query, It is throwing error called "TNS listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack".
For the first 2 to 5 times it is working fine.But, After a few requests(random), its throwing this type of error. Can u help me what might be the issue.
I am using express, oracledb and oracle 10g express edition.

Note: I am beginner to node and oracledb

Following is my code, when i get request:

```
oracledb.createPool({
    user          : "harsha",
    password      : "harsha",
    connectString : "localhost/XE",
    poolMax       : 44,
    poolMin       : 2,
    poolIncrement : 5,
    poolTimeout   : 4

}, function(err, pool) {


    if(err) {

        errorHandler(res);
        console.log("Error in pooling with oracledb"+err);
        return false;
    }else {

        console.log("Connected to oracledb successfully");
        //select r, v1.* from (select rownum r , v.* from (select * from employee) v) v1 where r>0 and r<=10;
        var gen_query = "select r, v1.* from (select rownum r , v.* from ("+query+") v) v1 where r>"+start_sequence+" and r<="+(end_sequence)+"";
        // connection.execute("select count(*) c from "+tname, function(err, result) {

        //  if(err) {

        //      res.json({
          //            dbStatus: 'E',
          //            data:"Invlaid syntax "+err
             //    });
        //      return false;

        //  }else {

        //      console.log(result);
        //      totalRows = result.rows[0].C;
        //      console.log(totalRows);
        //      connection.execute(gen_query , function(err, result) {
             //        if(err) {
             //          console.log("Error in results"+err);

             //          res.json({
             //             dbStatus: 'E',
             //             data:"Invlaid syntax "+err
             //          });
             //          //res.status(200).send(err);
             //          //errorHandler(res);

             //          return false;

             //        }else {
             //          console.log(result);
             //          console.log(totalRows);
             //          if(end_sequence < totalRows)
             //          {
                //         res.json({
             //                 dbStatus: 'S',
             //                 data: result,
             //                 moreRowsToFetch: true
                //         });
                //       }else {

                //          res.json({
             //                 dbStatus: 'S',
             //                 data: result,
             //                 moreRowsToFetch: false
                //         });
                //       }
             //        }

          //        });
        //  }
        // })

        pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {

            if(err) {

                console.log("Error in connecting to oracledb"+err);
            }else {

                connection.execute("select count(*) c from "+tname, function(err, result) {

                    if(err) {

                        res.json({
                            dbStatus: 'E',
                            data:"Invlaid syntax "+err
                        });

                        connection.release(function(err) {

                            if(err) {
                                console.log("Wrong with releasing connection");
                            }else {
                                console.log("Connection is released");
                                //res.end();
                            }
                        })

                        return false;

                    }else {

                        console.log(result);
                        totalRows = result.rows[0].C;
                        console.log(totalRows);
                        connection.execute(gen_query , function(err, result) {
                            if(err) {
                              console.log("Error in results"+err);

                              res.json({
                                dbStatus: 'E',
                                data:"Invlaid syntax "+err
                              });
                              //res.status(200).send(err);
                              //errorHandler(res);


                            }else {

                                if(end_sequence < totalRows) {

                                    res.json({
                                        dbStatus: 'S',
                                        data: result,
                                        moreRowsToFetch: true
                                    });
                                }else {

                                    res.json({
                                        dbStatus: 'S',
                                        data: result,
                                        moreRowsToFetch: false
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            connection.release(function(err) {

                                if(err) {
                                    console.log("Wrong with releasing connection");
                                }else {
                                    console.log("Connection is released");
                                    //res.end();
                                }
                            })

                        });
                    }
                })

            }
        })

    }

})
```

Comment: @AlexPoole  Hey i have added my code. I don't think i m releasing improper connections. If there is any wrong in releasing, please can u help me out? when i restart my server..it is working fine. But after few requests it is repeating the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your pool defaults look like the old example/webapp.js defaults.  I'd drop the max pool size for initial testing and when hacking around as a single user.  Recently the sample app was changed to use the same lower values as the hardcoded defaults.
- Make sure you are up to date with node-oracledb.
- You may find using something like 'async' makes handling errors easier.  See examples/plsqlarray.js for one sample.
- If you are throwing load at an under configured DB, you might see the ORA-12516 error.  You might need to bump the DB 'processes' setting, e.g. 'alter system set processes=100 scope=spfile;'  I used to see your error with the default Oracle XE 11g when running PHP regression tests.